# Comparing two arrays in jQuery regarding CSS classes

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two arrays. One looks like this:

```
var array_one = [".a", ".b", ".c", ".d"];
```

`.a`, `.b`, `.c` & `.d` are CSS-classes that can be found in the DOM.

Then I got another array `array_two` which holds all elements with class `.lorem` currently in the DOM.

Now how do I find the elements that have `.a`, `.b`, `.c` or `.d` **and** `.lorem` by comparing the two arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery's [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) method, coupled with [Array's `join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join);

```
$(array_two).filter(array_one.join(","));
```

Comment: @Christoph: I don't see why it won't work... can you explain in more detail?

Comment: my bad, missed the `","` concatenation, thought it was `" "` at the first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `array_two` is a jQuery object you can do:

```
array_two.has(array_one.join(","));
```

This is using the [`.has(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) jQuery function.